# How to bound uniformly this integral?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

could someone help me with this question please?

I need to prove that if $1<p<2<q\;$ and $f\in{L^p(\mathbb{R^2})}\cap{L^q(\mathbb{R^2})}$ then $$g(z)=\int_\mathbb{R^2}\dfrac{|f(y)|}{|z-y|}dy$$ is uniformly bounded.

I tried to write that as

$$g(z)=\int_{|z-y|<R}\dfrac{|f(y)|}{|z-y|}dy+\int_{|z-y|>R}\dfrac{|f(y)|}{|z-y|}dy$$ 
But I only know how to bound each one if $p=1$ and $q=\infty$ after fixing a concrete $R$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $R=1$. The first term
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{|y|<1}\dfrac{|f(z-y)|}{|y|}dy&\le&\left[\int_{|y|<1}|f(z-y)|^qdy\right]^{1/q}\left[\int_{|y|<1}\frac{1}{|y|^q{^*}}dy\right]^{1/q^*}\\&\le& \|f\|_q\left[\int_{|y|<1}\frac{1}{|y|^q{^*}}dy\right]^{1/q^*}\le M_1<\infty
\end{eqnarray}$$ by Holder's inequality since $1\le q^*<2$ ($q^*$ is a Holder conjugate of $q$) and $y\mapsto |y|^{-s}$ is locally integrable for $s<2$. We can check this using polar coordinate $dy = rdr$. The second term is estimated similarly:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{|y|\ge 1}\dfrac{|f(z-y)|}{|y|}dy&\le&\left[\int_{|y|\ge 1}|f(z-y)|^pdy\right]^{1/p}\left[\int_{|y|\ge 1}\frac{1}{|y|^p{^*}}dy\right]^{1/p^*}\\&\le& \|f\|_p\left[\int_{|y|\ge 1}\frac{1}{|y|^p{^*}}dy\right]^{1/p^*}\le M_2 <\infty.
\end{eqnarray}$$ This is because $2<p^*<\infty$ and
$$
\int_{|y|\ge 1}\frac{1}{|y|^s}dy =\int_1^\infty r^{1-s}dr<\infty
$$ for all $1-s<-1$. Gathering them together, we get an upper bound $M_1+M_2$ independent of $z$ as wanted.

Comment: Don't you use that $1<p$?

Comment: So, $1<p$ is an unnecessary hypothesis?

Comment: @mathlife Umm .. Now I got what you meant. $p>1$ is necessary to show $p^*<\infty$. But even if $p=1$, the argument is still valid using $p^*=\infty$ norm. In this sense, $1=p$ is also allowed. In the same spirit, $q=\infty$ is also allowed.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks